# useEffect going in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const CaptureFormValueContext = () => {
    // Grab values from context
    const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
    useEffect(() => {
      if (values.selectedCustomer !== formData.selectedCustomer) {
        const filterConexion = Lo.filter(conexionData, {
          CustomerName: values.selectedCustomer,
        });
        const mapConexionData = MapConexionListDropDown(filterConexion);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setConexionData(mapConexionData);
        }, 500);
        if (values.selectedConexion !== formData.selectedConexion) {
          setFieldValue('selectedConexion', values.selectedConexion);
        } else {
          const val = mapConexionData[0].label;
          setFieldValue('selectedConexion', val);
        }
        console.log('done');
      } else {
        const filterConexion = Lo.filter(conexionData, {
          CustomerName: values.selectedCustomer,
        });
        const mapConexionData = MapConexionListDropDown(filterConexion);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setConexionData(mapConexionData);
        }, 500);
        setFieldValue('selectedConexion', values.selectedConexion);
      }
    }, [values, setFieldValue]);

    return null;
  };
```

Above is the function, I am using to filter values based on customer. here what i am doing is I am selecting customer from the customer dropdown from the filter and based on that customer, i am to trying filter conexion. I am able to filter values. But in the end after filtering the values.

The useEffect is going in infinite loop it keeps on filtering again and again with same value.

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong or what i am missing?

Comment: Try removing `setFieldValue` from the dependency array.

Comment: You're using `setFieldValue` inside `useEffect()` and set it as dependency, it changes everytime `useEffect()` runs, resulting in infinite loop. You should've got a warning from `Es-Lint` about this

Comment: @yudhiesh already tried this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is the useEffect meant to be run whenever `values` changes?

Comment: @yudhiesh Yes, whenever the value.selectedCustomer changes. It will filter conexion

Comment: @yudhiesh they used `values` in the callback function so ES-Lint will give a warning that it must be included in the dependency array

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the useEffect hook should only trigger when `values.selectedCustomer` changes. The infinite loop is caused by `values` getting changed every time the hook got called, which invokes another hook call and so on.

To solve this, try making the deps array `[values.selectedCustomer]` instead of `[values, setFieldValue]`

Answer (score 0):

I think that Minh's answer is on-track, but I know my linter would complain if I had that code in `useEffect` without including `values.selectedConexion` in the dependency list, because it is referenced. However, I'm wondering if that reference can be removed. After all, here's the relevant code:

```
if (values.selectedConexion !== formData.selectedConexion) {
  setFieldValue('selectedConexion', values.selectedConexion);
} else {
  const val = mapConexionData[0].label;
  setFieldValue('selectedConexion', val);
}
```

Why would you call `setFieldValue('selectedConexion', values.selectedConexion)`? That's basically a no-op. Is it possible to just call `setFieldValue('selectedConexion', mapConexionData[0].label)` without testing `values.selectedConexion !== formData.selectedConexion`? As long as useEffect is dependent on `values.selectedConexion` *and* changing it, you're going to get caught in this loop, I think.

That said, if your linter doesn't stop you from doing as Minh suggests, it should work.